# Prevent a hidden field from postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to prevent a hidden field from posting its value back to the server? The purpose of it is to render a large list of comma separated values that I need to know in the client but I do not want to post back.

Thanks,

Comment: You can always make it disabled (disabled inputs do not post a value), but why are you using a hidden input anyway. Just assign the value to a javascript variable if you only want it in the client

Comment: Thanks, I was considering hidden fields as I use many partial views that are reloaded through Ajax. The problem is that an MVC project with Razor is organized such that your scripts (or references) are located in the main (non-partial) view. That it is a bit non-intuitive. However, the solution with hidden fields (that can certainly be located in the partials) introduce other problems so I will take your suggestion of using a variable. Thanks a lot,